# Como Generar una excepción en C# evitando el retorno de un valor

Tags: c#, windows-forms, excepciones

Tengo la siguiente clase que es usada en un formulario de logueo para consultar si el usuario es valido o no:

```
class LoginService
    {
        private const string URL = "http://localhost:3001/api/auth/";

        private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        public async Task<UserLoguedResponse> login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
        {

            string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
            //MessageBox.Show(httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
            if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                throw new Exception($"No se pudo establecer la conexion con la base de datos({httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString()})");
            }
            var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // hasta aqui todo bien
            UserLoguedResponse userLoguedResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserLoguedResponse>(response);// Newtonsoft.Json
            return userLoguedResponses;
        }
    }
```

El problema que se me presenta es que quiero generar una excepción en caso de que me devuelva un *badRequest* Pero hasta donde tengo entendido, mas allá de que generemos el error siempre va ejecutar el *return* de la función. Hay alguna forma de evitarlo? o mejorar de alguna manera el comportamiento para que luego pueda capturar el error y mostrarlo en un mensaje?

Tengo conocimientos muy básicos de Windows forms. En Javascript simplemente habría retornado la excepción, pero en C# es muy explicito el tener que retornar un tipo de dato concreto.

Comment: Estoy pensando retornar un null luego de la excepción, será lo indicado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Te ayudare con unos detalles:**

**1.** Para poder controlar de mejor manera lo que retornas y tener a la mano lo que necesitas, podrías empezar creando un modelo que te servirá para cualquier momento como un Response, que contiene la información de los datos que quieras retornar (result), el error que podría ocurrir (message) y un código de error para validar (codError). Algo como:

```
public class Response
{
    public Object result { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int codError { get; set; }
    public Response(object data, string error, int coderror)
    {
        this.result = data;
        this.message = error;
        this.codError = coderror;
    }
    public Response(){}
}
```

**2.** Ahora con este modelo, lo podrás poner como retorno de cualquier método que lo necesites. Por ejemplo en su caso ya no retornaría `Task<UserLoguedResponse>`, si no que retornarías un `Task<Response>`. Algo como esto:

```
public async Task<Response> login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    try
    {
        string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginRequest);
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(data, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await client.PostAsync(URL, content);
        //MessageBox.Show(httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString());
        if (!httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            return new Response( new Exception($"No se pudo establecer la conexion con la base de datos({httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString()})"), $"Error", 500);

        var response = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // hasta aqui todo bien
        UserLoguedResponse userLoguedResponses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserLoguedResponse>(response);// Newtonsoft.Json

        return new Response(userLoguedResponses, $"OK", 200);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return new Response(null, $"Error: {ex.Message}", 500);
    }   
}
```

**3.** Sugiero hacer uso del bloque `try catch` para hacer un buen manejo de errores.

**4.** Para manejar el error y validar que todo este correcto con el método puedes validar de la siguiente manera, o también podrías validar con el código de error con la misma lógica del siguiente código:

```
LoginService LoginService = new LoginService();
LoginRequest LoginRequest = new LoginRequest();

System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Response> task = LoginService.login(LoginRequest);

//SI EL LA CADENA DE CARACTERES DEL MENSAJE DE ERROR ES MAYOR A 0
// QUIERE DECIR QUE OCURRIO UN ERROR Y EL MENSAJE SE ENCUENTRA EN 
// ESA VARIABLE
if (task.Result.message.Length > 0) 
{
    //PRESENTAR EL MENSAJE DE ERROR AL USUARIO
}
else 
{
    //OPTIENES LA INFORMACION QUE TE DEVUELVE LoginService 
    // EN CASO DE NO HABER NINGUN ERROR
    object data = task.Result.result;
}
```

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Yo en el controlador por default del Response siempre lo seteo en "error" con un mensaje por default, para asi siempre sea error hasta que llegue al punto que necesito y volverlo "OK" por experiencia asi te ahorras muchos detalles de control. Solo comentario pues, es una gran idea siempre tener un objeto Response, ayuda mucho.